# How To get DiVs Level?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, getelementsbytagname

```
$html ='<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="">
        <div class="">
           <p><strong><span style="color:#FF0000"> Content1 </span></strong></p>
           <p style="text-align:center"> Content2 <img src="https://example.com/bla1.jpg"/></p>
        </div>
       
        <h2> Header </h2>
        <div class=""><p><strong> Content3 </strong></p> </div>

    </div>

    <div class=""> Content4 </div>
    <div class="">
                   <p> Content5 </p>  
                   <p> Content6 </p> 
                   <span> blah.. </span>
    </div>
</body></html>';
```

I need to have such an array:

This means whether each DIV (including P) has a child or parent DIV ?

Comment: Why specifically using `getElementsByTagName`? If you use `XPath` this task would be so much simpler

Comment: I do not know xpath can you help with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours is a nice attempt but I would rather prefer to get all `p` tags and then climb up the DOM node hierarchy if `div` is a parent of the current `p` node. This way, you would only collect those `p` nodes which has `div` as their parent and not otherwise. In other words, it is like the CSS selector `div > p`.

```
$ps = array();
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($HTML, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p){
   $curr_node = $p->parentNode;
   while(property_exists($curr_node,'tagName')){
      if($curr_node->tagName == 'div'){
        $ps[] = $p;
        break;
      }
      $curr_node = $curr_node->parentNode;
      if($curr_node === null) break;
   }
}

print_r($ps);
```

---

**Update #1:**

To get `p`s per `div`, you can recursively walk through all child nodes per `div` and collect all `p`s and add it to result as below:

```
function getPs($node,&$result){
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $c_node) {
        if(property_exists($c_node, 'tagName') && $c_node->tagName == 'p'){
            $result[] = $c_node;
        }
        getPs($c_node,$result);
    }
}

$ps = [];

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div){
   $child_ps = [];
   getPs($div,$child_ps);
   if(count($child_ps) > 0) $ps[] = $child_ps;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($ps);
```

---

**Update #2:**

To get the HTML string representation of the `p` node, change

```
$result[] = $c_node;
```

to

```
$result[] = $c_node->ownerDocument->saveXML( $c_node );
```

Comment: thank you very much.
But I need exactly the above format for the output.
With the original html structure

Comment: @yaradan You just group the data by parent div using associative arrays or use recursion to walk through all child nodes of a `div`

Comment: @yaradan Updated my answer. You can use `->textNode` I believe to get the HTML part of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot
This code works great.
How can I use saveHTML in the output? That is, instead of "content", I have "the whole element".
That is, instead of "Content1", "<p><strong><span style="color:#FF0000"> Content1 </span></strong></p>" should be printed

Comment: @yaradan Any issues?

Comment: Hi . I'm sorry about the wrong edit. Can you reply to my new edition? thank you

Comment: @yaradan You should rather put that as a new question instead of editing the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are committed to using only `getElementsByTagName` in combination with parent/child selectors you would probably find a simple `XPath` query much the simplest approach to finding the `p` elements located within `div` elements.

```
$html ='<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="">
        <div class="">
           <p><strong><span style="color:#FF0000"> Content1 </span></strong></p>
           <p style="text-align:center"> Content2 <img src="https://example.com/bla1.jpg"/></p>
        </div>
       
        <h2> Header </h2>
        <div class=""><p><strong> Content3 </strong></p> </div>

    </div>

    <div class=""> Content4 </div>
    <div class="">
                   <p> Content5 </p>  
                   <p> Content6 </p> 
                   <span> blah.. </span>
    </div>
</body></html>';


$tmp=array();


$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $html );

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query('//div/p');

if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node )$tmp[]=$node->textContent;
}

printf('<textarea cols=100 rows=10>%s</textarea>',print_r( $tmp, true ) );
```

Which yields:

[image: example output]

**Update:**

Rather than storing the nodeValue / textContent you wish to store the full HTML contained within the node so to that end you `clone` the node (& it's contents) and save that to the output array.

```
$tmp=array();


$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $html );

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query('//div/p');

if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node ){
        $clone=$node->cloneNode( true ); //clone node with ALL children
        $tmp[]=$dom->saveHTML( $clone ); // save the HTML within
    }
}

printf('<textarea cols=100 rows=10>%s</textarea>',print_r( $tmp, true ) );
```

[image: updated output]

Comment: thank you very much.
But I need exactly the above format for the output.
With the original html structure

Comment: OK - made a change above which I think satisfies your requirements

Comment: Thank you again.
This code is very close to my goal.
But I need to get the paragraphs(P tags) in separate division(divs).  In my example there are three 'divs' (nested and non-nested) containing 'P tags' . As a result the output must contain three cells of the array. As above.